# Creating a global climate model

Tags: matrix, modeling, weather

I'm trying to create a global climate model. The end result is for a game but my first goal is to create a working model.

I've read a lot about meteorology and I believe I understand the fundamental dynamics:

```
-Heat from Sun travels to Earth
-Clouds block Sun where clouds are present
-Surface heats up (moreso over land than water)
-Water vaporization occurs where water is present
-Hot areas become Low pressure zones
-Cooler areas become High pressure zones
-Low and High pressure zones create wind and clouds
-Wind and clouds rotate perpendicular to the line between the H/L systems (CW in N, CCW in S)
-Air pressure (specifically an increase) causes clouds to rain
```

Now I'd like to essentially forecast the weather and use the forecast as the weather for my program. It doesn't have to be very accurate but it should follow the same premises as we experience on Earth. I'd like if the fluctuations were sufficient to cause fairly variable weather conditions.

I'd prefer to keep the model in a tiled format, however that's not absolutely necessary.

I would start with a terrain (with altitudes) and likely a radiation pattern, which might differ each day, to emulate the energy input onto each tile. From there I can compare the type of elevation (mountain, land, water, etc) and the radiation, to determine the pressure. Previous waterfall in the soil could affect the humidity. From here I start to have an issue, as storms form on boundaries of opposing pressure systems and tend to move perpendicularly. This is hard to calculate when using a distributed number of points rather then actual systems with weights.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.easterbrook.ca/steve/?p=2183) for a list of open source climate models. There is also the [Java Climate Model](http://jcm.climatemodel.info/web/source.html), also open source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what I'm looking at in the first link, followed them down a few levels and didn't quite understand. Looked to be more about the current weather then how to predict it. The latter is more interesting but I'm sure the complexity of weather systems, when accurately modeled for our planet, is extremely complicated. I'm willing to do the work but sifting through source code and trying to understand such an advance system is probably less beneficial then understanding the overlaying concepts and creating my own approach.